# How to extending a Moodle plugin for Moodle Mobile app

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I want to develop a plugin for Moodle mobile app. So can it be done by extending a normal moodle plugin?. If so, please describe the process of converting a Moodle plugin to Moodle mobile app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the docs at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_Mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Moodle 3.5 the app switched to a new way to support mobile plugins. The new way will allow you to develop plugins using PHP code, templates and Ionic html components. Take a look at the following page. It will describe HOW to modify/update a plugin to support the Moodle Mobile App (Moodle 3.5+): https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Mobile_support_for_plugins

In short, you can use an existing plugin and convert it/extend it. Take a look at the mod/certificate plugin in Moodle 3.5+ as an example